# Order comments by timestamp in flutter doesn't work

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to order comments ascending after retrieving them from firestore,
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j5VVO.png)

My problem: Comments are not ordered with this code and I couldn't use orderByChild

```
DateTime timestamp = new DateTime.now();
String date = DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd – hh:mm:a').format(timestamp);





  addComment(String com) async {
    //User user = _firebaseAuth.currentUser;
    // Timestamp timestamp;
    print(date);
    final commentRef = Uuid().v4();
    FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("users")
        .doc(authorId)
        .collection("recpies")
        .doc(recipeId)
        .collection("comments")
        .doc(commentRef)
        .set({
      "username": userUsername,
      "reciepeId": "2cf0fbeb-957a-4330-96b3-36bc2fbfe080",
      "imageUrl": imageURL,
      "timestamp": timestamp,
      "shownDate": date,
      "comment": com,
    });
  }
```

------ and then i get the comments

```
getData(){
FirebaseFirestore.instance.orderBy('timestamp', descending: false)
        .snapshots()
        .listen((data) {
      setState(() {
        comments.clear(); 
        data.docs.forEach((doc) {
       
          comments.add(commentState(
              username: doc["username"],
              commentImgUrl: doc["imageUrl"],
              comment: doc["comment"],
             ));
        });
      });
    });
  }

}

 void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getData(); 
  }
```

Comment: I think, you have to set dateTime as timestamp in firestore

Comment: Thank youm it works with me

Comment: Please, Give upvote if work